# Beginner project in c++

Tags: programming, project

I am a cse undergrad and I have recently finished basics of c++ language to further improve my command on it I was looking forward to making a project.
I am thinking of a simple ray tracer .I know c++ basics , basic
Data-structures and some algorithms . Is my project overambitious? or should I first learn more before tackling it?

Comment: A ray tracer seems a bit steep to me.

Comment: Ray tracer is a difficult, [book-length](https://pragprog.com/titles/jbtracer/the-ray-tracer-challenge/) project. Have you done any self-driven projects before? If so, what were some of them, so we can get an idea of where you're at? If not, I'd suggest Tic Tac Toe, or another [command line game or app](https://github.com/asweigart/PythonStdioGames) (link sends you to Python-based repo, but the list of ideas works in any language).

Comment: Beginner project and C++ probably don't belong in the same sentence. Now ASP.Net with C# on the other hand, will get you very far very fast. But you might not learn a whole lot from it.

Comment: A raytracer project would require learning five things at the same time: geometry, linear algebra, basic C++, a particular graphic C++ library, and data structures to store and manipulate all the objects that you're rendering. Which makes it all the harder compared to a project which would only require basic C++ and algorithms.